# Problem after reinstall firefox

Tags: 16.04, firefox

After uninstalling firefox using `sudo apt-get purge firefox`
and deleting `.mozilla/firefox/` in home directory. I tried to un/reinstall it again many times, but I always got this message when I ran `firefox -v`

```
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /opt/firefox/libxul.so:
libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

Has anybody any idea how to resolve this problem?
I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS

UPDATE: I tried to remove /opt/firefox/ directory and this is what I got when I ran `sudo apt-get install firefox`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
 fonts-lyx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 firefox
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/46,3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 112 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 465446 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../firefox_53.0.3+build1-
0ubuntu0.16.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking firefox (53.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive 
/var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_53.0.3+build1-
0ubuntu0.16.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/firefox', which is also in package firefox-
mozilla-build:i386 39.0.3-0ubuntu1
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-
0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_53.0.3+build1-
0ubuntu0.16.04.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Where are you getting your copy of Firefox? Ubuntu repositories? Mozilla?

Comment: Try this command `sudo apt update && sudo apt install --reinstall libdbus-glib-1-2`

Comment: I have updated my question, please review it.

Comment: Remove the old version of Firefox first.

Comment: @heynnema I tried, didn't work

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Confirm which Firefox software is installed...

```
dpkg -l *firefox* | grep ii
```

Then uninstall the current Firefox...

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox-mozilla-build
```

And install the new version...

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
sudo apt-get install libdbus-glib-1-2 # use only if install fails, then retry install
```